# google adsense search in requirejs module

Tags: requirejs

To reduce load blocking I decided to convert the following google custom adsense search code...

```
<form action="http://www.google.ru" id="cse-search-box" class="form-search">
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="partner-pub-7920375793574512:1188291711" />
        <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" />
        <input type="text" name="q" size="55" />
        <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Найти" class="btn btn-info" />
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" async src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">google.load("elements", "1", {packages: "transliteration"});</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="http://www.google.com/cse/t13n?form=cse-search-box&t13n_langs=en"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" async src="http://www.google.ru/coop/cse/brand?form=cse-search-box&amp;lang=ru"></script>
```

... to (I just removed scripts to `require js` load style)

```
<form action="http://www.google.ru" id="cse-search-box" class="form-search">
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="cx" value="partner-pub-7920375793574512:1188291711" />
            <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="UTF-8" />
            <input type="text" name="q" size="55" />
            <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Найти" class="btn btn-info" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

... and require js module:

```
var scripts;
  scripts = ['http://www.google.com/jsapi', 'http://www.google.com/cse/t13n?form=cse-search-box&t13n_langs=en', 'http://www.google.ru/coop/cse/brand?form=cse-search-box&amp;lang=ru'];
  define(scripts, function() {
    return google.load("elements", "1", {
      packages: "transliteration"
    });
  });
```

And got unpredicted result:

when page is loading first it is ok, but then I see white screen without any html element and no errors in google chrome console.

So loading google scripts in `require js` module breaks all html. Why it is so?

Answer (score 0):

I added `window.` in line

```
return google.load("elements", "1", {packages: "transliteration"});
```

so got line:

```
return window.google.load("elements", "1", {packages: "transliteration"});
```

And all works fine.

Full code of `require.js` module:

```
var scripts;
      scripts = ['http://www.google.com/jsapi', 'http://www.google.com/cse/t13n?form=cse-search-box&t13n_langs=en', 'http://www.google.ru/coop/cse/brand?form=cse-search-box&amp;lang=ru'];
      define(scripts, function() {
        return window.google.load("elements", "1", {
          packages: "transliteration"
        });
      });
```